# Как сделать соотношение сторон для блока?

Tags: html, css

```css
.ex1 {
  border: 5px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="ex1">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAkGBxMTEhUSEhMWFhUVFxgVFRcWGBcYFRcYFxcXFhcVFRUYHyggGBolGxUXITEhJSkrLi4uGB8zODMtNygtLi0BCgoKDg0OGxAQGy0lHyUtLS0tMi0tLS01MC0tLS0tLS8rNS0tLS0tNTUtLS0tLS0uLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLS0tLf/AABEIAJ0BQQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAABBQEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAFAQIDBAYABwj/xABGEAACAQIDBQQGBwcCBAcBAAABAgMAEQQFIRIxQVFhBhNxkSIyQoGh8AcUUmJyscEVIzNTgpLRouEWVLLxNENjc8LS4pP/xAAaAQACAwEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADBAECBQAG/8QAMBEAAgIBAwIFAwMDBQAAAAAAAAECAxEEEiExQQUTMlFhIoHwcZHBFCNiM6Gx0eH/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/APK6dSMLGnVBZE2HxLJfZO+rBzWX7Q8hVI0jVRwi3lovuaXUknxDObsbmmDePGkFKu8eNWxhcFep3E0opUQncCac0ZG8EV2UXUJYzjgQ7qbTzTbVCLNCrT6au+pLa1DLJcDZN1MFSyjSohvrkc1yOekIp7iktXHNCwyFSON+HG/Qc62+Q9lb2lxQud6xeyvWT7TdNw61D2IyMWXFSgXOkCn/AK7HieHTWtJm+Z90VSNe9mZltCgZpWS4DFVW5Fhrc6U3TRFLfMxtZrZyl5FIF7c5biJUjEClkBO2ikDlsm2lwLEe+hWWdgnYAzybF/ZQBmHi24HwvW/hyvM5BdMEiDh386q3vWNXt50k+X5jGLyYHbHE4eZJD47DhCfdRJSplLLYCEdXCvbGOP2z+fYzOC7D4eN1cvI+yQQGK7JI1F7KDv4XrT2qtgcxjlLKpIdfXjdSkqfijaxFW7UxCMUvpELZ2SeLOqGWrrU+1dar5BDLUlqktSWqSMGOzHNculkKuSrg2EqqykEcpF3+/SrkOJmiUOGGLg+2lu+UfeUaSe6x6UMzLsDcs0EtrkkI40HQOOHurNRSYnAzW1RuKnVHH5MOo1FZ9sIy4sjj5Rt6abgv7E/sz1PLsakybcbBlOn+QQdx6GgWc5OUvJEPQ3sv2eq9Oldgk+sIMZhf3UxuHU/w5CuhWQDfu0ffRrK80SZTcd3Ih2ZI2I2lP6qeBG+szUaaVTyuUbej18buOkl1RjQdOlXsvxjREEH/AHFEM6yXfJCLj2kH5r/ihUUEm4o39ppbJqpqSNlg8aJBcHxHKkx2EWVSrjwPEHmKzWDaRDcKfI/GtJhsUGW50PEGuBSjteUYzH4JoW2WF7+q3BvDkelGMjzu1o5T+Fj+RotjDDIpR2Ug9RcHmORrI4zCd2xW4ccGB/O240RezOypcMK9r8W6mLYdlBDX2SRfdbdVfsvi3eRg7sw2b6m/EUOxuGxDhAUdlUHZOyePX3Ve7L4V0lJZWA2baggbxVljGCrWDTmlvXFhzFLtLzHmKoVE2q6l215jzFdXYOyeLy+sfGlprU6tEyzq411cagkQVPhIdph01NQii+U4f0S195/KqWy2xyOeH6fz7lHHHV/YhmxYX0UA0p2DxO2wRgNap4sem3iatZOgMngCRQpRioZHNNqrrdTGGeG8Y7Y9v2LkmT3Pok+Fr+VqH4rAuh1FxuuOfLpWnw02wwYcKlzGRGYMvidOPD30CN8l1N3U+D0WehbX7rp90Z5cqK2LnU8Bw8TUyYJeXxNMzjFPt23C2lvjQ8zMfaPKmFmSzk8xbHypuDXKNpkGTxNtF0VgNBcX4XvRZsrhG6KMf0isZlsrBLhiL8vKulne/rN5mhOLz1LqXHQ1c2ESxsqf2ihM+EEsiYcWAa7ykWGzEnra8LkhfeaAzym3rN5mtZ9H+C9CWdte8buxf7CaHzYnypjTU7prIl4hqXVS2ur4C+MwJxbR4LDhdpwsveD1cPGhFpgRxuLKOJvwBr0vs52bgwaFYlu7aySv6Usjc3f9BoOArOfRPlscWEkxQVUGJkeQcAsKErGByWwL/wBZrJ599IGMzHE/Usouqm470aO4HrSbR/hRjn6xuOJtTFs3OXwhDTUqqCS6s9nrq8XxH0PY1122zAPLvs3ekX5d4WJ9+z7qyMPaLNMqxBheVw0ZG1FKxliYHcVufVI3FSPzFDwmH5Pee1HZeHGKC37uZL91OmkkZ8faXmp0NYPBSyBpIJwFnhIWQD1WB1SVPuMNRy1HCtp2E7YxZlDtoNiVLCaIm5QncQfaQ2Nj0I3ihP0i4TYnwmLXeznCS9VkBeMn8MiWH/uGjUTcJY7MV1lCsrb7r8wDLV1qdaq+AwMuOmaCFzHDEQMTOttraIv3EN9z2ILN7II4mnpzUFlmLVTK2W2JWmzJRJ3MavNN/KhXbcdX4IOrEVdTKcyYXGCRRykxCBveEVgPOvQclyaDCxiLDxhFGptqWPFnY6sx5kk1fpKWqm+nBrQ8Pqivq5PKMVBjYhebAS7I3tCyTW67KkP5A0PmhwuOjsbSBTzKujcQRoynmDXs9Zftb2PTE3mhIhxaj0JlGjfcmX20PXUcKmOqfSayiJ+Hx61PD/PuY7B4NIkEca7KLuA8ybneSeNCu0eTGUd7FpMg04B14xt+nI1byC6xtHJtiaJ2WcSNdhJvY33bJuCttLEUSIpxxjOGOxlbp025T5TB/ZyZXw8bA8LEHeGBsynqDep5OOorLdpMIYZxIlwk5s1uEoG/+ofEUFkkbWxNYdtLhNpnstLqldUpo3GIP3hVSSRdk+kNx5ViJ2JOpNQMaqq/kO7cdg4zj7XKmKV4sPMVn7/pSCibAPm/B65BIuwtmHqjiOVVpSPtCsOxNrdPkGqrMevSh7A2/BuJF19YUPzBfQOtY+RzfeajMrcz5mrKv5Ku74D+w3yTSUB71vtHzNdVtpTzAeRup9NPCnUcSR1IaU0hqCzOFaTs5Ftqq83t5ms4K0nZ59lUYcHv5Gl9V6DX8F/1pP8Axl/ACxY/eP8Aib8zT8FLsup8/A1b7S4fYxUoG4ttjwcBv1oeo1FXWHH7GfXKVc1JdUzUFha/CocxnVUQpIru2pVddgcLn7XShLYk7AUnQfNqVIvR2utvKlVTjqeou8WjOKcXgjxMxbQm9RKlSSLrXWpqKwsI87dY7bHOQbwGDZowRbx/SufAPqDbfV/J2CwgsbAAkngKtZdlUmK9Ni0UB3W0llHMH2F+J6UOuE7JYiVvvqohumzK4xNiwLDa19He39o1r0js/hDHg4ktZu6BI+8w2m/1Mat5flcMAtFGq8yB6R6sx1J8auCtaijy+WzzGu139RhJYSBXaLMjF2XwojNjNFBASORXakHvCMp8TQj6AMTGuLxCMQJJIk7u+8hGYyAeaG33elTZzh2fLsVl41kwsn13Dji+HLEyBeZjMkgsOGxzryzDzsjLJGxV1IZWUkMpG4qRupRxx9JqRmpJSXc+wa8J+n7ERtjMOikGRIW7228BnBjB8nNvvda9B+iTtBJjMFtzzd7MkjI+ihgNClwoG8a3trryoN9PGCgODSZgonEqpE2m2ym+2nMrsja6ECqrqXPMPo0zlsLmOHYGyyuIJBwKykKL+DFW93WvbPpQYHD4dOL4zD7P9DGVv9MZrwnsJlzYjMMLGoJ/fJI1uCxHvGJ5aJbxIr2DtNjhiseEQ3iwQYMeDYmQAEA8e7juD1kI4USEczSBXTUK5N+xRzjGdzBJKBcohKjm25R7yQKsZp2mTJcLBgYU7/GuoZl4d5IbtJJbUlnJso1PQa1Q7SOFiQt6v1jC7f4frEV7+6sB2ez4PnEONxJ9F8QXctuQMGWO/JUungFo2oeZJCfh8UoOXyeljsZnGLXvMXmjYdm1EMAYKn3SY3S/+rxNY3tGM5yeRS2NleNz6EhdpI2IFyjJLtbLW4ctx32+gga89+nLExrlhRrbcksYiHG6ttMR/QGHv60rlmlhDPo5+kxcaww2JCx4m3oFb93NYXOyD6r7zs3Nxu4gei18ewzMjK6MVZSGVhvVgbgjqCK+q+yWb/W8Fh8SRZpI1LAbg40cDptA1Ml3KoxX0l5FF9cw2IdbpPfDyrc7LSKpkhZ1Bs1gsi69OVMtRn6WIlfDYeNvbxcIsCQd0haxGo9ENuoJh4FRQiCyqLAa6DxNOaR/Q/1MnxJfWn8A3tJgu9w0iD1gNtPxJ6S/EW99YzD4PbRXB9YA+YvXo5FYjKobI6W/hyyJ7g5t8CKX8QWMSQ74HPLlW/1BU+AO+9VnwJ11rQ4mI23GqbwnkazlNnoXBGcK0uxU7Ib7vm9MkU8qPkWcTQDLSyght400586pyZa3MGtBhEPdqLeyPyqtKnTjQdzyM7U0ZubBsDvGtVpYCBej2KGu6h+KT0avGTBSrQOsaSp9Pk0tEyD2gtuFLSPwpaIK9zjSGlrq4k6j2Al2IA3K5+NAa0mVYUSRKjNsqdWY8FBLMfIGl9Q+Fn3Nfwj1Wv8Awl/BW7Tm8kTHe2HiJ8dkj9Kqx4ElO8B0HCkzjHCaZpALLoqDkigKo8hVrJZtTGdzbqJBYSTMybfLQPNFMNDeNOtz8apY2HYYij+Dh/dpp7I+OtUseEMVYlyBJ4gGIpRHrV3EwEu3yKUwjfy18qru4LbQzkuDGIdIiP3MKq0o+251SM/dA9Ij8NbkCgXYnDbGEjY+tLeVv6z6P+kKKPVr6atQgjyWv1Duub7LhHUtq6lo4kUsxwRfYkjfu5ojtQyAX2TaxVl9pGGhXiK8z7T5JaQsqCB2N2gJ/dFjvOElPosh392xDruAI3es0yaIMpVlDA71IBB6EGg2VKXPcb0+qlVx1R4jgcdicJJtxPLA9rErdSRyIOjDoamxGKxWOk2pZGmcD1pHAVF4ksxCovlXqnYTsbgcTCMRLaSRye8w6sY4oGBsYjChBJFtS177xVrtd9HuFUHFQ9xh1ijO2skQeAhSW27Agh9bX1vppSMm10NuLTazwZfsdGuHR0wcitPKNibG7o4k4xYNWsZHvvkIC3sdbAVrcvwSRRrHGPRHW5JOpZjxYm5J43oFl3YHEzxJI2HwUe2obZdHLqDqAygaG3C+laDs/wDRlh4Uf6zZ3dtoGIywrGLW2UIfa63Jq1F7XWGPugOs0qnjbZle2Girn2A7/Dyw8XUhfxDVfiBXh7KQSCLEXBB4EaEGvdM1yvBYb1c1kgPBHlTEXPIRuDI3gDXmnaHJpZZZ5Y1L7GwzkRSQs4cEiQQSekNBrz3gUWyan06gdPXKnKk1g2X0H9pZmnbCTYhmjEV4I3sfSVhcKxG1ot7Le1r6aV6n2sw0EmDnXFBe6EbMxb2bAkMDwYHcedfKUchUhlJUg3BBIII3EEag9aIZp2hxU6BMRiZZEFiFdyVuNxIOhPU0BrI6ngGITYX321r6e+jDBtFleEVgQTH3ljvHeMZACOGjCvJfo6+jabFyJPiozHhVO1ZxZ5reyqnUIeLHeNBvuPV+1Ha9YCcNhQs2KtYIP4cI3B52HqqPs7zbTnUvnhEZS5fQD9t8WJ8dDAuq4RTNL0llXYiTxCF2/qXnVY1Wy3Bd0p2mLyOxklkb1pJG9Zjy5AcAAKtGtCqGyODA1V3m2bl07DTWXyxLtieX1iT/AON61BrMdn8UndO7MoMksz6ngZGA+AFKeIP6EaPgi/vN/A/EpoLVWMPXhRKWWM2sVPvHu3VDIyWOo8xWOeqMjIvpH/HX50qMx6/PCijKtvK3n+vKmSxgn3/lv+d1GTAtGoij9Abtw/KqssVFkiXYHgPyqrLGtqHnkKugFniN6H46L0fn3UeljF6G5pENkW5irJlWgHry+Irqn7sfOzXVfIPBmH4UtI+8V1NGf3Frq6uNcSdRpzbDDwHxNBRR/MsO0cOw4swC3HK9jb40C7rFfJr+Gei5/wCDAYqaF9lgRwqFBc0TwuTTPYhdOtFMzKXUt5om3GJB76IS5rHGqoNSFA08BxpuDwbRju5BvFxy+d1QJkbSMxVgLHW+/od1VnDdgiq7ZlA7EZiSSQAL1DPj32W14Hh0opJkNiV7wE8QL2HQm2+hGKw5UlD4V2xIurd3CZ67k6WghA4RoP8ASKjbO4BOuH7xTK17KNbEC9mI0BsN2+splsmOxsUaRn6vAqKjSb5JNkbLbHEC4O63id1afJOz8GFH7pfSPrO2rt7+A6CwrUhJtLB5ayuMW9759l/IWpaSlooudSikpRUEmXbK4pcbiS6XISCzAlWFw97MpB1sPKrM/Z6J12GkxJTQ7JxM5XQ3Hos5GhAPup8OmPnH2oYGHuaZT+lFaxNTKStlhnu/C6q56SDcU+Pb5BhyVTvmxZ8cViP/AL01uz2HPrIX/wDceR/+tjVrH5lFCAZHALaKupdjyRBdmPgKjjlxcmsODYDg2IdYgeuwNp/MCgpzfcclHTw6pfsVMxyZFgYYaGNJF2ZI9lVW7xsJEuQOagVcyjMRipsXi1uEmlUIGFiFjhjSxB3ENtio8ZFmEUbyumDCRqXb99NcKoJOpituFSdmcOUw0YYWdgZH/HKTI3xantDF7nkwPHrK3XHb1fx2RDmHZmCRjIF7uQ72QL6X40YFH94NJgMqmw7BoGwYYe02AhEnjtRMn5Uarq0HVB9UedhqbYLCkVMV9cmFsRjpCvFMOq4dT4st5P8AUK7BYKOFdiJAg32HE8STvJ6mrRppq0YRj0RSy6dnqYhpppSa41cCDs+xfdYeWQb1RrfiIso8yK8+w0eygX7IA94HGtT21xN+5g+2/eP+COx18WK+RrOTHqf+3zurK1s8zUfY9L4NVtqc33ZVlOg13/Pyahbjr8ammO469N3z76hY0qjWZWZjTWkPWn2/KuaM3011ogJphk4h1UasBYbiQLfPGqbYx/tt5mtZ2SyyKbD7co22JKkEn0baAW+PvrK51hBFPJGlyqtYcetr0NY3YCZ4yio+Jcn1j5moziH+0fM00imPwoiQJtnd5XUy9dU4Iyys+8V1JJXXoot3FpaSuqCQr2YjU4lNqxtdlB0DOoJRbnm1qJYuCSYbDfxSbv0N9b8tazIreYCEiJO7Ki4uxIuSfG9Dde6aY1VrHTXOMV6lj7dxuV5IkWpG03M7qLiqQjl/mL/Z/vTxDJ/N/wBAouBBvJLioVIDMbbOt/zB6VRkxJbSMbC8/abw5CpMwUiNQTtemNo2tpra4HW1QCuOFRQBYUMznDbn86KCmTpdSKhrJaMtryXewuMCA4Vjw72LqrfxF8Q2vg1bC9ZTD9lgYo5Y5SJrCRHHqqSLhbcRrY89aq4xsXi5vqU1sKqqGlAPpyjiYuaH4cb7qaouWxJ9exk6qlTtlOHTv8F/EdpHlnEGBRZNlh30rX7pVvqARvJ1F/K/DUVTy3L44IxHEoVR5k82PE9at3pmKfcRnKPSK4HV1JXVJQC5ue7xWHm9lw+Gc8AWs8ZP9SEf1CpswxT7SQQANPLfZ2vVRR600lvZW404kgVbzHBJNG0T32WG8aEHeGU8GBAIPShOQ4z6nLK2ODs0myq4lELR92gsqMEu0Z2tpjcWJbfWdq9O3Lekel8I8RjCnyJPDzw/hmnyTs/Fh7vrJM3rzPrI3QfYXkq2FF6Bf8Y4D/nIfDbF/LfVTE9qzJ6OCiaVjp3sitHh16lmAMngo94pNQnJ4SNSd1dazKSSF7Xz960eBXXvCJJ/uwIb2P42AW3La5VZqhlmX90GZ3Mksh2pZG0LtuAA9lANAvAVerW09Plxx3PJ6/V/1FuV0XQ6krr0xpALAkAk2AJ3nfYc6YEh1Ia69ZPNsXJg8Ys7uzYae0b3JIiYbiBwG8/3dKiTwWhDe8LqHM8ytcTC0LEi9iCDqGGoNuIvwoHkedSRSfU8aQJB/DlPqyrwuefX3b9+pvWN7e4iOTZwwAMgIdm/lLyv9pt1uWvKqWtQW8Npou1+VjOf9vn/ALH4V+/kkxJFwx7uHpGhPpD8TEnwtTpVFtwq7DDZFA0AUC3u3W/Sq0sBtvrAsm5ycme0oqVVaguxSlUbrDdu+eFVpY/RbTgau4jD67+FVsTCQh9LhrpVUFATD9Kem8dT/tTlgBOp0v8AP/anYSD01HUD40cXNgUCr6N1JGtiRe3O1C54gNd/H/ejcsYtxofNELa3NBQfACli1O6qGNjAAPWjcmHFzqaHY+ABRrrfSiRYOS4A9hyrqs/Uzz+FLRsoBhgN64Vz0/DqCdeAvRuwl1Yqxk8Pn31ZiwBb20Hif8VFK4HWmLOd9V5CfSuoaj7NsRcvp0Un9aP5Ynd/uib2G0p6biPP86g7O5qXT07E3tUuPfZYMPZN/cfWFCjN7sMPOqLrzH9QmDTgajRri4pwNMCIssYZSp3EWoTGTuO8Gx8RRcGh2PTZcNwbQ+I3eY/KoOGg0tMBpQag41nZPEDulMmkcR2GbhcHRfK3nWkzzLsPjFQPZjtXSRGtIhAJujrqp+TXm+CxRUmO9kkIJ/GoOyfeCR7hWp7MBkYufVJAvw4g/mKSuqm5qx9F0H6qtNHTymniXGV78pf+jZ8DjMN7P1uIbmSy4lR96M2WTxUg9KZgs6hlOwr2cb43BSUeMb2b4Vtr0OzzK4Z0tNEkgH2lBI8DvHupmrXTjxLkzr/Cqp8w4YLvXXoLnmUpAyxYKbECeU/uYdsSRW02pJO9DMkajeQeQFXmyrMU3Nhp/ESQN8NsflTn9fSvU8GbLwq9enkuXrr0FObzrKYHwcpkVQ7CFklCqTYFrEEXINgRc23VPhM4R5O6KSxybJbZlieMlVIBILCxsWG48aZhdCfpYpPTWw9UWEdheQ8hTr0PzHMNgrHGpkmlOzFEN7HiSfZQbyx3CimE7GO42sVi5S59nDkRRJ0XQs/ix15Ch3amFXDCafR2XrMehHekvVKbDy4XErhpJDMkiNJDIwAkGwVDxybIAYjbUhgBcXvu1t0WuyNkd0QN1MqZ7JdR16znbXL2eJZ4tJsMe8Q8SB6y9dADbpbjR93A3kDx0odis+w0ejzxg8gwZj/StyamWGsMipyUk4rJPlGYriIUmTc4vbkdzL7jcV2a4BJ4nif1WFuoO8MOoOtZPs/LNFJOuFw7yQO23EXvCqEjUemL7PDQcBRk5TNN/wCLm9H+TDdI/B39Z/gOlQm5LoXnBQnlPC7e/wCfrgzmB7SzQw/VtnblSQwpN60VhexuPWYAHTkBeqkcI1uSzMdpmJ9Jm5k8/gKJ9qZ445oIVAVIkZ9lRYAudldB0DedD0x8V7k9Tp5afpwrM1UpbtvXB6Pw2uHl+bjDZtkQbI8BVVwKnTN4Cvrjdx0qB8ZGddpd/MVn8mwipiAL1TxxGwx6VbxGKjHtL5iqGOxsewQGX3EVKRzYKlNSZfH+8Qge0PzqscWn2rb+fl876mwWaRrIu+20Dp+lHwwDaNxKNDpVGYdN1MxHaOG28+VUJO0cX3vL51oKiwzkvckkU66UOzNfRGlLL2jiudG8hVLF52j2Fjv4gcKIosG5x9yrsnl/1V1N/aafe8zS0TD9gW6PuAHqXD+14VE9S4b2vwmmH0EF1GOaaK411SQH+zb2v+L9KOYh7yD3VnuzjWPv/SjMsl5QOopSxfUzQpf0II4b0S0Z9g6fhOq/491WgaoYHADEl5ZHcKGaONUYpohsSxGpJa9JmCNhLMZNuIkAhyO8S+l1Ptjpvp6NU/L3mPPVVec617hEGo8VFtoV48PEbq5Xp4aqBgTE9xfz8eNPBpMWmzJ0fUeI3/5poNccOkFxpoeB5EbjXo+T5rFLAlhs3WxW2gI0Yed683vVzJ8SqSbMs08ULesYWVdljYbTXUts6cCLUrqqFbDHsFqm4S4/P+D0vKMXtgoT6cZ2WHG3st7xTc7zaPDxlm9NiQkca6ySO2ixoOZPHgLnhVSHsRgz6bGaUsAdp8RMdocPVYAiiOXdmcHA4kiw0SyDc+zdxcWNnNzupXK6sck/ZfuVOznZ94tqedg2JmA7wj1UUarBH9xfibmn9oswMARIwJMRMdiCO9tpuLufZjUasfdvIojnWbx4WIzSk2FgqjV3c6LGi+0xOgFBclyxyzYrFgHESi2ze6wR71gTw3s3tHoBVdik90jlJr6UTZHlZw8TDb25pG7yeQkfvH4k8gNwXcAAKyHaTMyuZrHFE00rYYJGqkWDvIzNtMfVSyISa1ed5ikGyiR97PLdYYQdXPFmPsxrvLHd41a7N5B3BaeZhJipbd7IBYADdFEPZjXzO801C7Y9y+wC2pWR2P7idluzv1YNLKwkxMoHeyW0A3iKIezGPjvNHi4va4vvtxsN5t76GZ7nSYZAxBd3OxDEn8SVzuRB+Z3AamquQZQ6u2KxLB8VILG3qQpe4gh+6Da7b2IvyAXk3LMpMvGKilGJiPprxNpMIikghZnupINiY1Go8D5VkuyjxSSGHEF2L6xsZZAL8UIDW6j3jlRX6W5i+Y7IuRFDGunAsXc/ArWMMZ5EcjqCCOIPA09p5bEmAvpVsWuj9z1AdmsJxgRvxXb/AKiavYbCRR6Rxon4VVfyFZ/s32j27Qzm0u5WOgl8OT8x5VpL1sVyjJZieYvhZXLZZkeWprOACToBqT0pu1WR7bZ4Apw0Z9Jh+9I9lfs+J/LxrrJqEcsrTVK2ajEy2aY7v5pJuDt6P4V9FfgL++q16YBShTyNZLeXk9bCKhFRXYKbenx/3/3qsXNSGJzuUn3HzpgwUp3Ruf6TQkg7ZXc1Gxq9+yMQd0Mn9prv2FiT/wCRJ/aaugbyDr0+D1hRAdncX/y8n9tSRdmsXf8A8O/lUlcMgkkqAvROTs9ih/5LfCoT2exX8l6qsF3kFFqaTRP/AIdxX8h/KuPZvF/yH8qtlA2pewLrqJ/8N4v/AJd/Kuqcorh+wFapMLvP4T+VRNUuF9b3H8jV30ArqRmupK6pIDPZ/f7/ANKJSSfvlA11G6g2V4gICTWmyCMgbbDU0tZw2x+nmKRPlWzeTCzLo7GSMNoHVjdgOobX31wSGMtsYGQtqu0wW1tRfvGY2W3/AGopioY5U2ZBe2qkGzKeasNQazmPZ9vuWxEjRE7JB2Qx6FwLkcDTlGrW1Rl1Rkavw2fmOcHw+q5/gkyfEP3Mf7skbOh2hu4b+lqu/WX/AJTf3L/mqAgA0EJsNBZ/96Xu/wD0n/8A6f8A6qoct4nadT6BUr6S3INyOGh5VUR7i/OnxaEERyaffuPLaqGVdlyvA+kvv3jzrjiXapkWJRtFZTzsQarYthZdu/d7a95b7F/S3cP0rRz4HCzqAuwDa6NEVDL1BX8jRK69/cWv1Kpaym0y7k3aHGrh9iOTDJHCe7DTKxewAIHrqLAED3VXn7ZYgnZfMIhzGGhUv7r7f5VmM5yVYJAwv3b6BthZHD6DZu32t/jempEbWCYlh1ZIl8ltSV1Krk01+fc0tNarq1KP5+3Jtslx8cjDER4bHY2VCVWWUpsofaCByqIddbLfWtH9bzF/UwcMfWbEXI/piRvzrEdgs3+qYgxSARw4j7UgbZmUEhmPAMosbneFrfT9rsCmjYuAHkJFJ8gaWn1wln8+Ayyvj8+Sbs9knclppn73Ey/xJbWAA3RRL7EY5cd51qfPs8TDKuhklkOzDCnryvyHIDeWOgFAMx+kHCqpMG1O4BIVFYLpxaRgFUeZ6VY7JYIsq46c7eJxEasSRpEjAMIYh7Ki+vEnU1Vp+qR2eyLuRZO6ucVimEmKcW0/hwIde5hB3Dm29j5Ud2qg267vKo3klLBgoXZ8VjZLAhsRsC9t0UccdteoNWwn/pj4Vkcnzb0Ga/8AEklk8e8kd/yIokudnX5+d1GlnIaC+lBifLo5VKSQhlPD9QeB6iqByjEx6QTbScExClyvQSqQxHjerWBzO4JuN/OrH7THyamF04P6WUu01dyxNJg0ZXjZNJJUiTj3KkufB3Nl8qLYDJYYkCJELbyT6TMTvZmOpJ51wzLQdalGPFTO+c/UytOkrp9EcEy4Ff5S+QqDEJwCLp0FS/XetZeTPfSPib/G1UzkMo+4fIYbgvwpV2+lZw5yeY486kwec3YVxbBpbSdPOnKr9KEjNuop0ebdQajJ21hhVfmPOpAj8xQxMyBG+pf2gOdWTO2sTHh72BG7nVW78xQPN88PekA8QKpjPDprxqUmzuEaqMPfeKsbMnMVlsFnN2HpDjRD9s9RUP8AQlBrZfmKWgn7Y611R9icfJ5I1OhazA1MIxTwg5VomOk8lWurjSVxUnw+8eNaaLNLDRfjWZwfrCiUunkPf08KFYssapk1EMjOjy+OnielBMbjNpieZ/xUpjsPePM8T4cqpYtLOR1qsYovOTaCsePiYXe4bcdTY+RqQYmDm3m/+aAr+tOj3ii7hby0HxiIPtt5vXYnFxFRZzddQbMTbiKCqd1ORtQKjeW8pe4Yy/CPidQwSLiQQZD0AHq++tFgMHh4zaJIw6i1xYyWPM79awpgVtbWJNtPnWrGGiKqArsqsSCFsLgc2AuaYr1EYdhDUaC21+vj2C/azN1YfV0N9QZCNwsbhQed7eFqzu2vHaOnFmOvvNPxigbNhYWNgOh+JquB+VBssdj3Mb02njp4bF9yZHT+Wu7kD+dXoMxCjRQPAAULWpF3UJxTGYyx0CWNzUtG4A1ZSo15i1e5YVNhEQblVV/tAH6V4JgU2poFO5poQfAyKDXvBalr0kkkXUnJ8ljbqjnuM7vDTyfYikYeIQkfGpdqs/2+mIwE9uKqvuZ1U/A0CKy0iz4R5HhsUUUKOAA+FSnHHXfvqkwt50pO/wAa0HFAlNpYDOFzfZBGu+rKZ3zv40Cj/Wn36cao60FVkjRftoaDXhbp49Knjzsc/h8T06VmEbTdx+TViJtQPvWv151HlosrWaN8+Ftx47/zPXkKypxpvfxNXW/UgfqTzNBamEEUssZc+vH5/SnxZiQQaoGlWr7UD8yQXGbn5NSw5wQDp4a/DqKD1JHUbEXVkgymdHlf3/OlTjPm5eZ+J6chQNxa9uYv1+eVWO5tx9oD/eo2ot5kitjccWctzP8AioPrBpuIX0j41EKuksAJTlktQ4wg31qwuZNv/Why0+ucUSrJBH9qnr511UL+FdUbET5kvc//2Q==" alt="">
</div>

<div class="ex1">
  <div class="ch"></div>
</div>
```

Есть 2 контейнера. В одном изображение с размерами 321 x 157. Оно хорошо адаптируется со свойством object-fit: contain;
Помогите сделать аналогичное поведение для блока. Т.е. нужно чтобы красный блок вёл себя абсолютно так-же как и картинка в соседнем контейнере. Для этого вроде нужна функция вычислений соотношений пропорций.

Answer (score 1):

**Велосипед в студию.**

Нам потребуется помощь скриптов, чтобы узнать размер картинки.
После загрузки сайта получаем размеры `img` и выставляем их для `.ch`

Т.к. стоит `object-fit: contain`, который по факту растягивает картинку на всю ширину блока, пропорционально, а пустоту задаёт как прозрачный фон, то скрипт выдаст размеры блока родителя, в нашем случае `200x200px`.

По этому "пишем свой" `object-fit: contain`.
По факту, он работает так: изображение пропорционально занимает блок и размещается по центру этого блока.
Окей, этого нам хватит, костылим дальше.. и пишем такое:

```
.ex1 {position: relative}
.ex1 img, .ex1 .ch {display: block; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto;}
```

Для `img` и `.ch`, задаём максимальный размер в 100%, а так же абсолютное позиционирование и автоматические отступы. И вуаля, у нас свой `object-fit: contain`, даже для блоков.

И в итоге у нас получается вот это вот:

```js
$(window).on('load',function(){
  var imgW = $('.ex1 img').width(),
      imgH = $('.ex1 img').height();

  console.info(imgW+'x'+imgH);

  $('.ex1 .ch').css({
    'width': imgW,
    'height': imgH
  });
});
```

```css
.ex1 {
  border: 5px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  /*object-fit: contain;*/
}

.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.ex1 img, .ex1 .ch {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ex1">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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" alt="">
</div>

<div class="ex1">
  <div class="ch"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Предложу несколько вариантов. Первое, сделать родителя флекс контейнером, и позицанировать ребёнка по центру по х и y.

```css
.ex1 {
  border: 5px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Сделать ребёнка абсолютно позицанированным и задать маржин:

```css
.ex1 {
  border: 5px black solid;
  width: 200px;
  height: 220px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

Второй вариант абсолютного позицанирования:

```css
.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

И третий:

```css
.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 157px / 2);
}
```

Похожий на предидущий, но без абсолюта. Но осторножно с этим. Нужно будет задать высоту родителя вручную, поскольку % берёться от ширины родителя. Если блок квадратный, то никаких проблем:

```css
.ch {
  background: red;
  max-width: 321px;
  max-height: 157px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: calc(220px / 2 - 157px / 2);
}
```

Из абсолюта советую пользоватья первым либо вторым.

Можно использовать ещё и display: table-cell;, но вам понадобиться дополнительный div.